# find max difference between elements in vector

Tags: matlab

I want to evaluate the difference (susbtraction) between all elements in a vector and have the maximum as a result.

For example with

```
[1 3 7]
```

the diffs are 2, 4 and 6, so that the result should be 6.

How can I do that with matlab in a clever way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The maximum difference between any two elements in an array is the difference between the maximum and the minimum value of the array:

```
x = [1 3 7];
maxDifference = max(x) - min(x)
maxDifference =
     6
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this.

```
x = [1 7 3];   % order doesn't matter
MaxDiff = range(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (tested in Octave):

```
x = [1 3 7];
max(abs(x - [x(2:end) x(1)]))
```